# Slider in Javascript

Tags: html, css, slider

i've got a problem with slider in my project. When I trying to widen the window, the photos expand unnaturally. I use margins in percentage to move the slider.
Here is a code:

```css
.slider{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.slides{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;
    max-width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some HTML?

Comment: i can send you an image what i want to achieve because its quite complicated